# Separate shortcode for each field of gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This shortcode will display the gravity form in my wordpress page

```
[gravityform id="1"]
```

This form has 3 fields and on submit button. I want to get shortcode for separate fields so that I can display them in different positions according to my need.
Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

You can position the fields by drop&drag when you're building the form. Just click and drag the field up and down to your desired location.

You can find more help about shortcodes for gravity forms on their site: [Gravity Forms shortcodes](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Shortcodes)

Comment: But what about placing the field in a custom table which is formed by another WP plugin

Comment: I don't think that you can have a form and put fields all around the website. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Would this work for you? It is not tabbed but it is a multi-page form: [Multi-Page form](http://www.gravityforms.com/demo/multi-page-form-sample/)

Comment: thanks for your effort... but it would be more easier with tabbed navigation, or a method could be designed to make a custom shortcode to call only specific fields of gravity form with their field_id, i tried to make custom shortcode for this..but out of luck..